# UITextContentTypeEmail has no effect on quick type suggestions on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am currently trying to display quick type suggestions for the user's email address when the user is editing the email text field as well as the email confirmation text field. To do that, I set two things:
the text field's `textContentType` as well as its `autocorrectionType` to get the quick type bar to appear.

However, it seems that setting the `textContentType` has no effect on the contents of the quick type bar; it simply displays "words" as they would appear when editing any other text field. This is obviously not the result I want my users to see.

Here is the current code:

```
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"textContentType");
    // Make sure that the text field is actually able to process the event, 
    // the iOS version is greater than 10.3
    if([self.emailTextField respondsToSelector: selector]){
        self.emailTextField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeEmailAddress;
        self.emailConfirmationTextField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeEmailAddress;
        self.emailTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
        self.emailConfirmationTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, this works for 3rd party apps only starting from ios 11